# Is it safe to force remove /usr/local/lib/docker to fix a Homebrew permission issue?

Tags: docker, terminal, homebrew

I'm trying to cleanup my installed packages using `brew cleanup` but keep getting the message `Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins`.

I tried changing the ownership of `/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins` using `sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins` then ran `brew cleanup` again but this got the same result.

It might be worth noting that I do not use the Docker application anymore and don't even have it installed anymore. So I was wondering if simply force removing the /docker directory using the `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/docker/` command would help? Or would that do more harm than good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there would be any issue of deleting or reinstalling `/usr/local/lib/docker/`. You should be always re-installing the right Docker app and `brew link` it for the use.

But before you are doing that, I'd recommend you to run `brew doctor` first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @chenrui. I ran `brew doctor` before all this which returned a warning for 2 broken symlinks. One of which was `/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins`. The suggested fix was to run `brew cleanup` that's when I encountered the issue.

Comment: Got you, then I suggest just deleting the broken installation.

Comment: I removed the docker directory, ran `brew doctor` again followed by `brew cleanup`. No more errors, thanks!